# Azure Biz Spark - Adding Guest User

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, bizspark

I am on the Biz Spark program. My resources were moved from a normal account to Biz-Spark subscription and ever since then I cannot give access to external users/developers to my resources in Azure portal.

I add a user through the Azure Active Directory, then I go to the resource group which they should be able to access and make them "owner" level of that group. The guest user gets an Email invitation, but when they log in, they do not see any resources.

I've even tries adding the user as subscription admin as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator.

They still do not see any resources when they log in.

[image: Guest User View]

Comment: I have seen this behavior. What happens when these users try to login into Azure Portal? In my experience, the invitation process always failed however when the users sign in into Azure Portal, they are able to access the Azure Subscription properly.

Comment: No, they cannot see anything even if they just login directly.

Comment: Can you see any  subscriptions in Azure portal? (Go to Subscriptions to check:https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade)

Comment: No, the list is completely empty.